# If one vowed to fast for a set period of time, would he continue at sunset after Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, fast-days, nedarim-shevuot

So say someone had vowed to personally fast for a certain amount of time, and a portion of this time overlapped with Shabbat. Now it is known that we are forbidden from fasting during Shabbat, except of course on Yom Kippur.

So during this time, would one break his fast on the Friday night as he does every other night he fasts, then proceed to eat and drink the following Saturday. Then in order to fulfill his vow in complete succession, continue his fast at sunset until the sunset of the following Sunday?

Thank you for any help and advice regarding this matter.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A2

Comment: Thank you kindly for this.